# How can Rearrange/change type in the dictionary key values in dictionary , I do not want to sort it

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a `dictionary` with key values, But I want to rearrange/change the type of the keys/values in the `dict` so as per my like. How can I do it?

for Example:

```
Dict = {'a':19,'b':30, 'c':"New", 'd': 6}
```

I want to make `b` as key at position 1 and/or I want to make `a` key as a `list` and so on. 
NOTE: I dont not want to sort the dict! But decide myself :
Example:

If this key is present in dict then put this Key,value in Position 1

So my final result would be,

```
Dict = {'b':30, 'a':[19], 'd':6, 'c':"new"}
```

Comment: Dictionaries (in Python 2.7) are *not* ordered, there is no concept of *position*, there is however `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: So what would be the solution

Comment: Also why is `19` now in a list `[19]`?

Comment: I would like to make it as a list, its part of it

Comment: Why only `19` changes? How do you defined the new order? As I said you can use `OrderedDict` to preserve insertion order

Comment: I would like to mantain a certain order which has to be in a certain format to the convert in json. I get the key values from a dedicated output, and then based on the key values present , I want to order it especially depending on the keys i.e the type or order depends on the keys. 19 was just an example. it could be a dict or list of dict and so on

Comment: Since this question was closed, I can't suggest this as the official answer, but if you *need* your container to be a dictionary with arbitrary order, you "can" subclass Dict and then implement logic that would **dict**ate the algorithm by which you wish to represent the keys/values when interacting with the Dict. I'd probably just make a decorator and decorate functions that delegate to super(); unfortunately, the comment section is a little too small for a proper example.

Comment: @ReidBallard Thank you. Would look into it

Answer (score 1):

You can't put the key `b` in position 1, or any position. Dictionaries are unordered in principle. There is usually not much reason to care about the order.

But if you do care about the order then you have to maintain it yourself outside of the dict that holds your data. You can't insist on the dict maintaining the order itself, because dicts don't work that way. For example:

```
orderby =  ["b", "a", "d", "c"]
for key in orderby:
    do_something_with(key, Dict[key])
```

To change the order, for example to exchange the positions of "a" and "b":

```
orderby[0],orderby[1] = orderby[1],orderby[0]
```

There is also an `OrderedDict` in `collections`, but that is mainly to remember the order that things were added to it, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

To change the value associated with `'a'` just assign it:

```
Dict['a'] = [19]
```

Comment: I would like to mantain a certain order . I get the key values from a dedicated output, and then based on the key values present , I want to order it especially depnding on the keys i.e the type or order depends on the key

Comment: You can get the keys out of the dictionary in an ordered sequence, you just can't insist on *storing* them that way. Do it like this: `for k in sorted(Dict.keys()): do_something_with(Dict[k])`.

Comment: If you don't want them in alphabetical order, but your own arbitrary order, then you need a second dictionary to store the order: `{0 :"b", 1: "a", 2:"d", 3:"c"}`, or a list `["b", "a", "d", "c"]`.

Comment: I quite didnt get you, But can you explian me in detail ?

Comment: @jaison I covered this in an edit to the question. If there is something there that you still don't understand then please say what it is.

Comment: I have a dict which which I have to alter the key and values with some other values/key and then I want to maintain a order as per my wish.

Comment: I have already explained that you can *not* make a `dict` store things in a particular order. They don't work that way. So if you want to keep track of the order you need a dict, or list, or *something*, that does that: in other words *you have to store the ordering information in a separate data structure of your own*. The edit to the answer gives a simple example of how to go about this. I understand that you want the `dict` to do this for you. I'm trying to get you to understand that it can't and won't, and so you need another approach.

Answer (score 0):

The rearranging I think you cannot do as dictionaries are not ordered structures. The second one you can simply do by:

```
Dict['a'] = list(Dict['a'])
```